# assign variables directly to build in jenkins

Tags: shell, csv, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins, i have a wrapper script that runs overnight in Jenkins.
This wrapper script takes input from a .CSV file which contains list of projects. i had to give this way = ./wrapper_script project.csv
This has one problem i.e., it runs all the projects in one single build, but my requirement is i should run one build per project. I have already installed necessary plugins.

How can i give project.csv content as input to the build where i will trigger the wrapper_script.sh directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on [Job DSL Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Tutorial---Using-the-Jenkins-Job-DSL). You could create a seed-job that [reads the CSV file](http://www.groovy-tutorial.org/basic-csv/) and iterates over the records and creates a job for each record. If you need a more detailed code example, please include sample data from your CSV file.

---

Ok. Given that the CSV you provided it so simple, you could skip using the CSV library. Your Job DSL seed job would be something like this:

```
new File('project.csv').splitEachLine(',') { fields ->
    job(fields[0]) {
    steps {
        shell("your build command " + fields[1])
    }
}
```

Comment: The below is the csv file, it's just a part but it contains more than 800 rows

XJA1124,projects.abl_sja1124
TJA1146,projects.abl_tja1146
ADIS,projects.adis
amr_abcd9_int,projects.amr_abcd9_int
ATIC,projects.atic
BAP3,projects.bap3